# Assign text input value to a variable in Calabash

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

I'm evaluating Calabash coming from an Appium & Selenium background.

In Selenium i can simply assign the `.attribute("value")` to a variable and then do what I want with it. I'm looking for something similar in Calabash.

Specifically in an Android app (although I am looking for a cross platform solution) I have an `EditText` that I can query with `:text` and I can see the value in the output i.e.

```
irb(main):008:0> query("EditText",:text)
[
    [0] "17512"
]
```

How can I perform the same function as a step definition in calabash and assign the output (i.e. `17512`) to a variable?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped me get what I needed: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/how-to-get-the-text-to-verify-for-edittext-in-calabash-android

Particularly `actual_email = query("EditText id:'txt_email'", :text).first`

Comment: I believe that something like
   
actual_email = query("EditText id:'txt_email'", :text).[0], will work as well

Comment: Yeah, you're basically right, but it would be `:text)[0]` you don't need the `.` there.

Comment: Ups, keyboard misspeling :) ---------- 
actual_email = query("EditText id:'txt_email'", :text)[0]